# What is the difference between the different print functions in the fmt package?

Tags: go, printf

I have read the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) on the Go fmt package. Still, I don't understand the difference between Print, Fprint, Sprint, Printf, Fprintf and Sprintf. Could someone explain it to me in layman's terms?

Comment: The documentation is very clear. "Print ... writes to stdout", "Fprint ... writes to w", "Sprint ... returns the resulting string". What clarification do you need?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's the convention:

- If the name starts with Print, it writes to standard output
- If the name starts with Fprint, it writes to an io.Writer (possibly to a file,  thus the 'f')
- If the name starts with Sprint, it writes to a string and returns that string
- If the name ends with `f`, it is a formatted print, that is, it gets a format argument like "%s %d", and formats the output based on that.
- If the name ends with `ln` like `Println`, it prints a newline after writing
- Otherwise it simply prints its arguments using their default formats.